# iOS Add a view in xib but i still need to use addView

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, viewcontroller, addsubview

I have a view where I added a view2 in xib (with interface builder), i joined everything with my viewClass.
Everything is working.

But when I do in viewDidLoad :

```
view2 = [[[OtherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OtherViewController" bundle:nil]view];
```

I still have my view but i don't have the outlets from OtherViewController view. 
I have to do :

```
[self.view addSubview:view2]; // It works, i see my outlets
```

Can someone tell me why ? And how can i do ? I need to add the OtherViewCOntroller view without using addSubview.

TY

Comment: putting this as an answer as I can't comment yet Try putting your code into - (void)awakeFromNib{} Rather than viewDidLoad and see whether this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are using `storyboard`, there is a `Container View` that you can add as subview, and connect that container view to your `OtherViewController` by an `EmbedSegue` (if you are using iOS 6.0 or above). In this case you would not need any additional code to write.

Comment: TY for your answer but I'm not using a storyboard (not my choice btw), i really need to do this with a xib.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with XIB. Someone has to instantiate your view controller.